# how to update Items Ordered order qty in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, upgrade, edit-order

[image]
how to update order Items qty in admin panel?
(magento 1.9)

Answer (score 1):

update order Items qty programmatically.

please create **order.php** in magento root file and its run **www.domain.com/order.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('../app/Mage.php');
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();

    $order_id = 1234; //use your own order id 
    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id); //load order by order id 
    $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
       foreach($ordered_items as $item){     //item detail 
          $item->setQtyOrdered($item->getQtyOrdered() - 1)->save();
       } 
    $order->setStatus("complete");       
    $change = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order was set to Complete by our automation tool.', false);
    $change->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save();
 ?>
```